# Is there a way to specify a variable number of Observable in Observable.WhenAll()?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive, reactive, unirx

I'm applying reactive programming to the Unity3D project.
Is there a way to specify a variable number of Observable in Observable.WhenAll()?

Sample or search results suggest an explicit way to enter all non-variable items, most of which are not variable numbers.

```
var parallel = Observable.WhenAll(
                    ObservableWWW.Get ("http://google.com/"),
                    ObservableWWW.Get ("http://bing.com/"),
                    ObservableWWW.Get ("http://unity3d.com/");
```

What I want is as follows.

```
List<string> URLs = new List<string>();
URLs.Add("http://google.com/");
URLs.Add("http://bing.com/");
...
...
var parallel = Observable.WhenAll( ??? //ObservableWWW.Get() : count of URLs list);
```

Please reply.
Thank you.

Comment: The [WhenAll<T>(this IEnumerable<IObservable<T>> sources)](https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx/blob/aa3b6d3e30354c25f5ee276d19be4f5ff7d7a82c/Assets/Plugins/UniRx/Scripts/Observable.Concatenate.cs#L260) overload already accepts an arbitrary number of observables. Perhaps you're looking for a way to *produce* a list of observables from a list of URLs?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos He wants a second parameter so he can say that only 2 of the Observables have to be completed like Observable.WhenSome(urlObservables, 2)

Comment: @FelixKeil there are no observables in the second snippet. Even if there were, a count parameter isn't meaningful when you can limit the number of items in the `IEnumerable<>` with a `Take(2)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Take(2) selects concrete Observables out of the Enumerable. Which Observables finish shall not matter. So this is not a solution how I understood the problem. But maybe you are right. The question is unclear.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Seems you are right what the question is about. I have conceptual solution in my head for a WhenSome extension method, where it doesn't matter which observables are finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WhenAll(this IEnumerable> sources)](https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx/blob/aa3b6d3e30354c25f5ee276d19be4f5ff7d7a82c/Assets/Plugins/UniRx/Scripts/Observable.Concatenate.cs#L260) already does this. I suspect the *real* question is how to produce some observables from a list of URLs. One way to do it would be to use LINQ :

```
var urlObservables=URLs.Select(url=>ObservableWWW.Get(url));

var allAsOne= Observable.WhenAll(urlObservables);
```

**Update**

As Felix Keil commented, what if the OP wants to observe only a few of those observables? That's a job for LINQ's [Take()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8), applied either on the URL list or the observables list, eg :

```
var someObservables=URLs.Take(2).Select(url=>ObservableWWW.Get(url));
```

or even

```
var someObservables=URLs.Select(url=>ObservableWWW.Get(url)).Take(2);
```

LINQ's lazy evaluation means the operators will run only when `someObservables` gets enumerated. When that happens, enumeration will stop after the first two iterations so `ObservableWWW.Get` will be called only twice

Comment: Great!Your solution is perfect.
It's working as I wanted. Thank you all for answering.